# Are all scripting languages interpreted?

Tags: scripting, scripting-language, interpreted-language

Are all scripting languages interpreted? I haven't come across a compiled + scripting language yet. the following languages are both interpreted and scripting languages. what is the connection between interpreted languages and scripting languages.

> e.g JavaScript, python , perl

what about the reverse?

Answer (score 6):

By definition, what makes a scripting language is that there is not a separate compile stage. A scripting language always need a copy of its interpreter around to run while a compiled language doesn't need the compiler to execute the resulting binary. For example in C we would first compile to a native executable *then* run that executable.  In a scripting language, we feed in the script as a text file and it is immediately executed.

How this is accomplished is another question.  Most scripting languages begin life with a purely interpreted implementation.  Inevitably the useful ones all acquire an implementation that takes advantage of the speed of Just In Time(JIT) compilation.  The difference is that this JIT is done during the running of the script and never produces a separate output. Scripts are still human readable text files that require some interpreter to run.

There are some interesting example of languages "on the border."  Haskell is normally compiled into a free standing binary, but can be run as a script as well (at least the GHC implementation can do so.)  Java compiles to a binary, but not a stand-alone executable.  A Java runtime must be present to run Java files.